# Trying to build container app from ACR throwing unauthorized error

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-container-registry, azure-container-apps

Have a question on Azure need to deploy an azure container app by pulling the image from azure container registry from AZ

Steps:

```
1- az login -successful
2- az acr login appdev - successful
3- az containerapp create --name apptest --resource-group \
testapp --image appdev.azurecr.io/dev/dev-app:latest \
--environment MyContainerappEnv \
```

Throwing this error:

the following field(s) are either invalid or missing. Invalid value: `"appdev.azurecr.io/dev/dev-app:latest": GET https:?scope=repository%3Adev%2Fdev-app%3Apull&service=appdev.azurecr.io: UNAUTHORIZED: authentication required, visit https://aka.ms/acr/authorization for more information.: template.containers.apptest.image`

I have already logged in successfully and able to pull the image using

```
docker pull appdev.azurecr.io/dev/dev-app:latest
```

Also this is successful

```
az acr login --name appdev
Login Succeeded
```

Able to push the image to ACR .
I already have **contributor** permission to the subscription.

Can anyone help? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this worked:

```bash
az containerapp create --name apptest \
  --resource-group testapp \
  --image appdev.azurecr.io/dev/dev-app:latest \
  --environment MyContainerappEnv \
  --registry-server appdev.azurecr.io //adding this
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to
   **your container registry** => **Access token** => set admin user to "**enabled**"
2. You should add a commend below during creating az containerapp using Azure CLI.:

`--registry-server appdev.azurecr.io`

**Azure Container Registry:**

`az acr create --resource-group $RESOURCE_GROUP --name $ACR_NAME --sku Basic '**--admin-enabled true**